# Any RESTful web services modules in joomla 2.5

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am new to **joomla 2.5**. I am creating a sample web page, where I added menus and displayed the articles in a page but I couldn't call the **RESTful web services** in my site.

I want to display the XML, JSON data on my web page in the format of html by using RESTful web service API

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I want to display json format in html view in my joomla website by using RESTful web services but I don't know how to dispaly html in cms could you please help me any modules is there in RESTful web services

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your own view for the XML and JSON output.

Basically you will create 2 new views (besides the view.html.php).

- view.json.php
- view.xml.php

You can also have a look at [K2](http://getk2.org/) (to replace com_content) or as an inspiration on how to build this -> [their repository](http://code.google.com/p/getk2/source/browse/trunk/components/com_k2/views/item/view.json.php).

Useful you may also find ["Generating JSON output"](http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_JSON_output) and some basic information about [overrides in Joomla!](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: thank you Valentin Despa.....but basically i don't know how to create a views in joomla 2.5 administration could you please tell me how to create a views in joomla

Comment: They need to be coded, there is nothing you can do from the Administrator website. I suggest you take a look at k2, read their cocs regarding what you need. Maybe it's already there.